# SOQL Strip Time or Date Construction

Tags: soql

Is there any way to use SOQL to strip the time out of a datetime column or to construct a date?

e.g. SELECT DATE('2001-12-31') would return December 31, 2001

Answer (score 0):

In some kind, you can do this, i.e.,

```
User a = [Select createddate from user limit 1];
system.debug(a.createddate);
system.debug(a.createddate.format('MM/dd, yyyy ') );
```

in the debug log, got

|DEBUG|2010-12-13 00:41:39

|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|12/13, 2010

It seems can't transfer 12 to December directly.